# Why PhpStorm doesn't have a docker tab in Cli interpreter for Mac OS?

Tags: macos, docker, phpstorm

Why PhpStorm doesn't have a docker tab in Cli interpreter for Mac OS?

[image: cli interpreter]

I'm not found answer for this question on web. Please, help me.

I have running Docker:

[image: docker in phpstorm]

**Version phpstorm:**

```
PhpStorm 2018.2.5
Build #PS-182.4892.16, built on October 11, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.6
```

**Version Docker**:

[image: Version of Docker]

Comment: Can you check you’ve got the *PHP Docker* plugin installed? It ships by default with newer versions, but it may not have been installed if you acquired the feature by upgrade.

Comment: Check what plugins you have enabled. You may need all 3 plugins: 1) Docker integration 2) PHP Docker 3) PHP remote Interpreter

Comment: Yeah! Thank you, @MTCoster and lazyone. It helps me!

Answer (score 1):

It happened because plugin **PHP Docker** was disabled.

1. Go to Preferences -> Plugins
2. Search plugin PHP Docker
3. Turn on the plugin
4. Restart application

[image]

Thank for @MTCoster and @lazyone. Sorry, but a must post answer there.
I hope it helps somebody.
Sorry for my english)